# How to determine which thread gains the intrinsic lock of an object?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
 public class ThreadA {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();

        synchronized(b){
            try{
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                b.wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread{
    int total;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        synchronized(this){
            for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
                total += i;
            }
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, an object, `b`, is synchronized. `b` completes the calculation before Main thread outputs its total value.
output:

```
Waiting for b to complete...
Total is: 4950
```

If the `main` thread gains the lock of `b` first, then the `main` thread will execute the `synchronized(b)` block. Will `b.wait()` suspend thread `b`(thread `b` doesn't run yet)? If yes, how can this code produce the result?

If thread `b` gains the intrinsic lock first, what's the result of `notify()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will `b.wait()` suspend thread b(thread b doesn't run yet)? If yes, how
>   can this code produce the result?

No, it's the `synchronized(this)` (where `this` refers to the same object as `b`) that will block the other thread. Once `b.wait` is invoked, the monitor on the object referenced by `b` is released, the main thread goes to sleep, and the other thread acquires the monitor, entering the `synchronized` block.

> If thread b gains the intrinsic lock first, what's the result of
>   `notify()`?

There are no threads waiting on `b`/`this`, so `notify` will basically do nothing. When your other thread releases the monitor, your main thread will acquire it and call `wait`, waiting forever since there's nothing else to `notify` it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i'm still unclear about the effect of `b.wait()` The fact is `b.wait()` causes `main()` thread to sleep, right? So `b` in the synchronized block refers to the intrinsic lock of object `b` instead of the object itself. `b.wait()` means whoever owns intrinsic lock of b needs to release the lock.

Comment: @leonf Yes, `b.wait()` will make the calling thread sleep. `b` is a variable. It holds the value of a reference to an object. `synchronized` uses that reference value to retrieve the object and lock its monitor (which we call owning the lock). When you call `b.wait()`, the calling thread also releases the monitor on the object referenced by `b`.

Answer (score 3):

When you use notify/wait you should do this based on a state change.  if you do not, you open yourself to a number of issues.

If you notify() when there is no thread waiting, the notification is lost. A wait() coming later might wait forever.

If you wait(), it can wake spuriously i.e. it doesn't mean there was a notify.

The solution is to either;

- not use notify/wait as it was largely replaced 10 years ago by the
  concurrency libraries
- have notify() thread change a field/state and have wait() thread
  check this in a loop.

As James Large notes, wait()ing is not fair in the sense there is no guarantee the first thread to wait will be the next one notified.

Also you can't change state without holding the same synchronized lock and expect it to behave correctly all the time.

Comment: And, when there is more than one thread wait()ing, for the same event (e.g., worker threads waiting for tasks to perform), then the fact that wait() returned in worker A doesn't guarantee that worker B didn't get there first and claim the task.

Comment: Re, "Have notify() ... and have wait()..." And also, insure that no thread ever changes the state without holding the same lock.